# How do I bind a variable number of list items when passing to an action result

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, mvvm

Everything works but I need to bind many possible "Regs". `Bind(Prefix = "Regs[0]",...` all the way up to `Bind(Prefix = "Regs[n]",...` some natural number n. So how do I iterate in this situation when the `foreach` would need to be inside what's getting passed to the `ActionResult` Index?

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix = "Main",  Include = "AlterationForseenChanges,AlterationGrowthDecline,DescriptionEcozone,DescriptionEcoregion,DescriptionEcodistrict,DescriptionPreviousDB")] SESData sESData
        ,[Bind(Prefix = "Regs[0]", Include = "RegulationName,RegulationDescription,RegulationURL")] SESRegulationsList sESRegulationList) 
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.SESData.Add(sESData);
        db.SESRegulationList.Add(sESRegulationList);
        db.SaveChanges();  
        return RedirectToAction("Report", new { id = sESData.id});
    }

    return View(sESData);
}
```

This is the basic Viewmodel

```
public class SESDataViewModel
{
    public SESData Main { get; set; }
    public List<SESRegulationsList> Regs { get; set; }
}
```

The view just has an undetermined number of Edtiors exactly like these

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Regs[0].RegulationDescription)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Regs[1].RegulationDescription)...
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Regs[n].RegulationDescription)
```

Comment: Start by getting rid of those dreadful `[Bind]` attributes. You never need a `BindAttribute` when using a view model properly - but view models do not contain data models.

Comment: And you POST method simply needs to be `public ActionResult Index(SESDataViewModel model)` and it will be correctly bound.

Comment: Thanks, I can't test it until Monday but cheers anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mr. Muecke for this effective and simple solution

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index(Models.SESDataViewModel sESData)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.SESData.Add(sESData.Main);
            foreach (var reg in sESData.Regs){
                db.SESRegulationList.Add(reg);
                db.SaveChanges();    
             }           
            return RedirectToAction("Report", new { id = sESData.Main.id});
        }

        return View(sESData);
    }
```